# os.walk stop looking on subdirectories after first finding

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

I need to get the first appearance of the repository.config files in a directory and stop looking in the subdirectories.

Here is my directory tree:

```
./WAS80/base/disk1/ad/repository.config
./WAS80/base/disk1/md/repository.config
./WAS80/base/disk2/ad/repository.config
./WAS80/base/disk3/ad/repository.config
./WAS80/base/disk4/ad/repository.config
./WAS80/base/repository.config
./WAS80/fixpack/fp5/repository.config
./WAS80/fixpack_suplements/fp5/repository.config
./WAS80/supplements/disk1/ad/repository.config
./WAS80/supplements/disk1/md/repository.config
./WAS80/supplements/disk2/ad/repository.config
./WAS80/supplements/disk3/ad/repository.config
./WAS80/supplements/disk4/ad/repository.config
./WAS80/supplements/repository.config
```

I need the ones in bold and stop looking in the subdirectories.

I started tinkering with this code, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
pattern='repository.config'
path='/opt/was_binaries'

    def find_all(name, path):
            result = []
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                    if name in files:
                            result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
                            continue

            return result
```

Comment: For one thing indent your code properly. Python is very space-sensitive. For another, don't start your paragraphs with "so basically".

Comment: What does "I started tinkering with this code, but I couldn't figure it out." mean? What does it do that you don't like or understand. Please be specific. Do not reply in the comments! Edit your question to be a stand-alone problem statement please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

this should do what you want:

```
import os

res = []

for here, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir, topdown=True):
    if 'repository.config' in files:
        res.append(os.path.join(here, 'repository.config'))
        dirs[:] = []
        # dirs.clear()  # should also work - not tested...

print(res)
```

whenever you encounter a `'repository.config'` file, set `dirs` to `[]` in order to prevent [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) from descending further into that directory tree.

note: it is vital for this to work to change the `dirs` in-place (i.e. `dirs[:] = []`) as opposed to rebind it (`dirs = []`).,

Comment: mindblowing... Can you explain how this results in some kind of feedback to the os.walk (generator?) operation so that it will skip further scanning?

Comment: Is this also possible if you are looking for a certain directory (ignoring the sub directories) instead of a file? How would that change the answer?

Comment: @Siete `os.walk` returns a reference to the `dirs` it will scan internally. all i am doing is change that (reference to a) list in-place - which in turn changes the list that is referenced inside `os.walk`. and sure: you can filter that depending on what you like. the important part is to reassign the `dirs` with `dirs[:] = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to make sure that `topdown` is set to `True` (this is default) so parent directories are scanned *before* child directories.

Create an `existing` `set()` to remember which directories you traversed when successfully found a config file.

Then, when you find your filename in the list:

- check if the directory of the file isn't a child of a directory you registered
- if it's not, just note down the path of the file in `existing` (add `os.sep`, so you don't match substrings of directories starting with the current dirname at the same level: ex: `path\to\dir2` should be scanned even if `path\to\dir` is already in the `set`. But `path\to\dir\subdir` will be successfully filtered out).

code:

```
import os

existing = set()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path,topdown=True):
    if any(root.startswith(r) for r in existing):
        # current directory is longest and contains a previously added directory: skip
        continue
    if "repository.config" in files:
        # ok, we note down root dir (+ os.sep to avoid filtering siblings) and print the result
        existing.add(root+os.sep)
        print(os.path.join(root,"repository.config"))
```