# Print number of occurrences of any items in a list in paths

Tags: python, list, count, shutil, os.walk

I am using `os.walk` to identify paths in a generic source directory (SRC) that contain any strings in `my_list`:

```
SRC = '/User/dir_1/'

my_list = ["dog", "cat", "mouse", "bird"]

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(SRC):
    for folders in dirnames:
        for x in my_list:
            if x in folders:
                source_path = os.path.join(dirpath, folders)
```

And let's say that `print(source_path)` gives the following:

```
/User/dir_1/cat_test/
/User/dir_1/cat_test/bird_results/
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/cat_results/
/User/dir_1/mouse_test/
/User/dir_1/mouse_test/mouse_results/
/User/dir_1/unknown_test/dog_results/
/User/dir_1/bird_files/
/User/dir_1/bird_files/bird_a_files/
/User/dir_1/bird_files/bird_b_files/
```

My goal is to `shutil.move` my source_path's, but since, for example, moving `/User/dir_1/bird_files/` and then trying to move `/User/dir_1/bird_files/bird_a_files/` will result in a FileNotFound Error, I want to filter my source_path's to include those with only 1 occurrence of any string in `my_list`, such that my source_path's are:

```
/User/dir_1/cat_test/
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/
/User/dir_1/mouse_test/
/User/dir_1/unknown_test/dog_results/
/User/dir_1/bird_files/
```

I have tried `source_path.count(x) == 1`, but that iterates through `my_list` as opposed to counting `any x in my_list`, such that my output is (for example):

```
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/cat_results/ count == 1 (for dog)
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/cat_results/ count == 1 (for cat)
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/cat_results/ count == 0 (for mouse)
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/cat_results/ count == 0 (for bird)
```

but I want to see (for example):

```
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/cat_results/ count == 2 (for any x in my_list)
```

Which would allow me to filter out any `source_path` with `count != 1`

Comment: Can't you just do `for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(SRC): print(dirpath.count("dog"))`, goal is a bit vague...

Comment: @Ferret My goal to exclude any source_path that includes more than one occurrence of any item in my_list (including multiple occurrences of the same item). So, e.g. /dir/dog/cat and dir/dog/dog would be excluded but /dir/dog would be retained

Comment: you should rather create list to keep `source_path` which you already moved and check next `source_path` with this list. Eventually you should use `os.path.exists(source_path)` to check if `source_path` still exists. Or simply use `try/except` to catch error `FileNotFound`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comprehension to filter by count, then sum the result (`True` is cast to 1) to get the "any" behavior.

```
paths = """/User/dir_1/cat_test/
/User/dir_1/cat_test/bird_results/
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/cat_results/
/User/dir_1/mouse_test/
/User/dir_1/mouse_test/mouse_results/
/User/dir_1/unknown_test/dog_results/
/User/dir_1/bird_files/
/User/dir_1/bird_files/bird_a_files/
/User/dir_1/bird_files/bird_b_files/""".split()


my_list = ["dog", "cat", "mouse", "bird"]

out = []
for path in paths:
    if sum(True for term in my_list if path.count(term) == 1) == 1:
        out.append(path)

print(*out, sep='\n')
```

Output

```
/User/dir_1/cat_test/
/User/dir_1/dir_2/dog_test/
/User/dir_1/mouse_test/
/User/dir_1/unknown_test/dog_results/
/User/dir_1/bird_files/
```

---

EDIT: From the comment, a `os.walk` approach.

Idea: remove terms from the `dirnames` parameter

Remark: I used as filtering condition (see comment in the code) the method *substring is contained in string* which is quite poor. In this special case a more robust one could be `d.startswith(c)`. For more flexibility use a *regex*-like solution.

```
import os


constraints = 'dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird'

wdir = './User' # your reference directory
res = []
for path, dirs, _ in os.walk(wdir, topdown=True):
    # local to each directory's content
    counter = dict.fromkeys(constraints, False)
    dirs_to_skip = []
    
    # filter by constraint
    for c in constraints:
        for d in dirs:
            if c in d: # <-- filter condition!
                if not counter[c]: # 1st match
                    counter[c] = True
                    res.append(os.path.join(path, d))

                dirs_to_skip.append(d)
    
    # remove matched paths          
    for d in dirs_to_skip:
        dirs.remove(d)

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Comment: for a in out: will allow you to use the "out paths" in shutil.move

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the unwanted paths instead of finding them and filtering them out later? For example, if the script finds /User/dir_1/bird_files/ it stops looking for "my_list" subdirs in that path (so, in that example,  /User/dir_1/bird_files/bird_a_files/ and /User/dir_1/bird_files/bird_b_files/ would not be captured). I have seen an alternative here (see accepted answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618746/os-walk-stop-looking-on-subdirectories-after-first-finding that is similar to what I am looking for, but it stops looking once it finds a single match in a dir level

Comment: I think that `os.walk` doesn't fit well to this case (also if the link you shared is quite good!) A recursive approach with `os.listdir` would be easier. I will give a try in next days:)

Comment: @Bot75 I added a new implementation, let me know if it makes sense